# How to use semaphores without using if-else, while, for, etc

Tags: java, multithreading, semaphore

This is homework, but I'm just looking for a nudge in the right direction (not someone to do my work for me).

- I have four threads
- They each print out their own numbers in a loop: 1's, 2's, 4's, and 8's respectively
- At the beginning of my main I must start all four threads and then end them after 500ms
- I am to use semaphores in order to ensure that only these numbers are printed in this repeating pattern: 111111112222448111111112222448111111112222448……
- I am not to use while, for, if, else, and so forth.
- I am using Java

I do not know how to definitively get that pattern to print out without using if statements and I am very unfamiliar with semaphores and only a little familiar with threading.

Could a kind soul give me some direction? Even if you simply point me to a wonderful video or article, I'll be appreciative.

*EDIT*: I'm sorry. I've made things confusing. There are already while statements defined for me inside each thread. Each while statement only prints one of its numbers at a time. Ex: It prints a "1" not a "11111". It's that I am not allowed to define any *more* while statements and such.

Comment: How are you supposed to generate a repeating pattern without using a loop?

Comment: I second Heuster's statement.  You can't repeat anything in any language without some sort of loop construct.  A Thread's run method will run straight through like any other method unless there is some kind of loop in it.

Comment: Well, only has to run for 500ms.  Maybe a huge amount of block-copy/paste?  Extraordinarily silly, yes, but after a question like this... :)

Comment: I would have one thread print all the numbers and let the other three do nothing.

Comment: Would it be possible to have the threads recurse until the threads are killed in the main method? That might overflow the stack, though.

Comment: @Heuster you can use recursion to repeat, but then again one would need a conditional statement to break out of it.

Comment: Sorry. Let me be more clear. The four threads run a while loop which continuously prints these numbers and I have a Boolean, stop which tells the threads to stop running.

Comment: If your homework is explicitly forbidding you if/else constructs you could use the ternary operator :D

Comment: @ortang that would defeat the purpose...

Comment: @thats_how_i_feel, i guess that's why a added the *:D* ;)

Comment: @thats_how_i_feel are you allowed to use the modulo(`%`) operator?

Comment: @ortang I am, I think.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Java's semaphores, I am assuming then a call to acquire() is blocking. So with that in mind, if a thread tries to ***acquire*** a semaphore that's already acquired by another thread, it would have to ***wait*** until it is free to ***acquire***

Comment: That is right, but I guess my main concern is how to know how to get it to run the while statement a certain number of times (8 in the case of the 1's) and then tell it to go to the two's if that makes sense. The code I was given looks very similar to @Heuster's except that my while statements don't print "11111111" every iteration, they print "1".

Answer (score 1):

You will need a semaphore for each pattern. The first one should be initialized at 1 (since you want that thread to run) and all others should be initialized to 0 (since you want to block those threads at first).

Every thread should start with decreasing the value of it's semaphore (that call is blocking if the value of the semaphore is 0). At the end of thread 1, you should increase the value of the 2nd semaphore. At the end of thread 2, you should increase the value of the 3rd semaphore, and so on. At the end of the last thread, you should increase the value of the first semaphore again, to start over.

Since I don't want to do your homework, I'll give an example with only 2 threads:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Semaphore thread1Block = new Semaphore(1);
    final Semaphore thread2Block = new Semaphore(0);

    Thread thread1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                // reduce the value of the first semaphore by one
                // blocking if the value is 0
                thread1Block.aquire();

                System.out.print("11111111");

                // increase the value of the second semaphore by one
                thread2Block.release();
            }
        }
    });

    Thread thread2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                // reduce the value of the second semaphore by one
                // blocking if the value is 0
                thread2Block.aquire();

                System.out.print("2222");

                // increase the value of the first semaphore by one
                thread1Block.release();
            }
        }
    });

    // start the threads
    thread1.start();
    thread2.start();
}
```

**EDIT**

I apparently misunderstood the problem. The tricky part is to use the semaphores in such a way that they serve as counters. I would do it in the following way (again, only 2 threads as an example):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Semaphore s1 = new Semaphore(8);
    final Semaphore s2 = new Semaphore(0);

    Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                s1.acquire();
                System.out.print("1");
                s2.release(4 * ((8 - s1.availablePermits()) / 8));
            }
        }
    });

    Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                s2.acquire();                   
                System.out.print("2");
                s1.release(8 * ((4 - s2.availablePermits()) / 4));
            }
        }
    });

    t1.start();
    t2.start();
}
```

The trick is that each semaphore is also used as a counter: only when the first semaphore has value 0, the second semaphore's value will be incremented by 4. Similarly, when the second semaphore has value 0, the first semaphore's value is incremented by 8.

Comment: According to the OP, since he can't use a `for` loop to generate the print statements, and since the threads have to run in a specific order (so you can't easily write a reusable Thread class without getting probably-too-complex), I think this answer is best.

Comment: To be more clear, there is already a while loop inside of my threads which prints out only *one* of these numbers at a time. How do I know when it has printed out enough 1's or 2's is my question.

Comment: @thats_how_i_feel I misunderstood the problem. I added what I think is the correct solution.